# Visual Studio Xamarin missing multiplatform library template for NuGet

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, multiplatform

My goal is to create a multi-platform Xamarin library that is to be used by Xamarin.Forms application for iOS and Android. About 10% of the library code is going to be platform-specific (bluetooth communication). The library is plain C#, it won't use any Xamarin.Forms or platform-specific graphics. In the end I would like to add the library as a NuGet package.

I planned to implement the library using [the multiplatform library template for NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/nuget-multiplatform-libraries/single-codebase). The problem is that I don't see the template at all (*look at the pictures below*). I'm using Visual Studio for Mac 2022 (version 17.4.2).

**Templates I should see (according to docs):**
[image: Templates I should see.]

**Templates I actually see:**
[image: Templates I actually see]

**Visual Studio Installation:**
[image: Visual Studio Installation]

**Questions:**

- Is the "Multiplatform library" still supported in Visual Studio for Mac? (as of 31.12.2022)
- If it is supported, what am I missing?
- If it is no longer supported then how would I create the library I described? I'm a bit new to the Xamarin ecosystem.

Comment: You could report this issue to the product team on the Developer Community site. About how to report a problem with the Visual Studio product or installer, see : [Report issues & bugs - Visual Studio for Mac | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/report-a-problem?view=vsmac-2022)